# Magento - Cron job stops working while adding a function for order status change

Tags: php, magento, cron

I'm using Magento 1.9.2 and I'm developing a custom extension.

Here is my config file of the extension:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <automatedstatus>
                <file>automatedstatus.xml</file>
            </automatedstatus>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <automatedstatus>
            <class>VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vivasindustries_automatedstatus_resource</resourceModel>
        </automatedstatus>
        <vivasindustries_automatedstatus_resource>
        <class>VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <automatedstatus>
            <table>VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus</table>
            </automatedstatus>
        </entities>
        </vivasindustries_automatedstatus_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <automatedstatus_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                 <use>core_setup</use>
             </connection>
        </automatedstatus_setup>
        <automatedstatus_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </automatedstatus_read>
        <automatedstatus_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </automatedstatus_write>
    </resources>    
    <helpers>
        <automatedstatus>
            <class>VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus_Helper</class>
        </automatedstatus>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <automatedstatus>
             <class>VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus_Block</class>
        </automatedstatus>
    </blocks>
  </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <automatedstatus>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>automatedstatus/observer::setStatus</model>
                </run>
            </automatedstatus>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>  
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <automatedstatusadmin>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </automatedstatusadmin>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>  
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

For developing purposes I have set the cron job to run every minute.
Here is my `observer.php`

```
class VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus_Model_Observer
{
   public function setStatus() {
        Mage::log("The order status was changed!");
    }
}
```

Like this every minute I can see that the cron job is done by seeing that `The order status was changed!` message is added to my `system.log` file

However when I change it to this:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus_Model_Observer
{
   public function setStatus() {
        $orderId = "100005082";
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true);
        $order->save();
        Mage::log("The order status was changed!");
    }
}
```

In the `system.log` file there are no longer `The order status was changed!` message added and also the order status is not changed.

I am pretty sure the problem comes from the code for order status changing.

Where is my mistake how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You must use loadByIncrementId() instead of load().

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
```

Actually, in Magento, the Order State "complete" must not be set manually. It requires the order to have Invoice and Shipment created first. If you really want to mark it as complete, you can do it as follow:

```
public function setStatus() {
    $orderId = "100005082";
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
    if (!$order->getId()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!$order->canInvoice()) {
        return false;
    }

    $savedQtys = array();
    $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice($savedQtys);
    if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
        return false;
    }
    $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
    //create invoice
    $invoice->register();

    $invoice->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(false);
    $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

    $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
            ->addObject($invoice)
            ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

    $transactionSave->save();

    //create shipment
    $shipment = $order->prepareShipment();
    if ($shipment) {
        $shipment->register();
        $order->setIsInProcess(true);

        $transaction_save = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                ->addObject($shipment)
                ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                ->save();
    }
}
```

Then the order state will automatically set as COMPLETE.

Comment: Still i can not see the message in the log file also the order status is not changing.

Comment: It is because The Order state "complete" should not be set manually. To make order state COMPLETE is to create invoice and shipment first, then the order state auto gets COMPLETE state.

Instead of COMPLETE, try to change it to PROCESSING:
        `$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);`

Answer (score 0):

When you use $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true); Magento throws exception "The Order State "complete" must not be set manually".

So you need to change the way to set state manually. Please try this

```html
$orderId = "100005082";
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$order->setData('state',Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
$order->addStatusToHistory(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
$order->save();
```